# How to convert varchar to int to get average?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to get the average of each `user_id` for a specific time period.

Since `RIGHT` works on strings , I have to convert it to `int` and get the average.
For that reason I get error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '08:36' to data
>   type int.

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    avg(convert (int , right('0' + convert(VARCHAR(2),datediff (second, QueueEndDt,ConnClearDt)/ 60 % 60), 2) + ':' +
    right('0' + convert(VARCHAR(2),datediff (second, QueueEndDt,ConnClearDt)% 60),2)))  as average_minutes
FROM Detail
WHERE QueueEndDt between  '2015-02-09 08:00:00.000' AND '2015-02-09 23:02:33.043'
group by user_id
```

Without using the average and convert I get the correct `datediff`.

I made a http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/298eb with some data.

What I would like to output is average of each user_id.

Comment: You can't convert non-numeric string to INT. 08:36 clearly is a string. Post sample data and expected results.

Comment: What if the average is more than 60 minutes? How do you want it displayed?

Comment: @wewesthemenace hh:mm:ss

Comment: How about days? years? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return you the average difference in `hh:mm:ss` format. Note that `hh` may exceed to 24. Modify the query to add years, months and days part.

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT
        user_id,
        Average_Seconds = AVG(DATEDIFF(SECOND, QueueEndDt, ConnClearDt))
    FROM details
    WHERE
        QueueEndDt BETWEEN  '2015-02-09 08:00:00.000' AND '2015-02-09 23:02:33.043'
    GROUP BY user_id
)
SELECT
    user_id,
    [Average hh:mm:ss] =
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Average_Seconds / 60 / 60) + ':' 
        + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),  Average_Seconds / 60 % 60), 2) + ':' 
        + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),  Average_Seconds % 60), 2)
FROM CTE
```

**RESULT**

```
user_id    Average hh:mm:ss
---------- ------------------
number1    13:44:16
number2    13:50:36
number3    13:46:33
```